# Relation between bounding box coordinates in object detection

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, bounding-box

In object detection, what is the difference between the set of coordinates `left top right bottom` and the set `xmin ymin xmax ymax`. Are they the same thing? If not, is it possible to convert from one set to another?

Comment: They are the same thing. Left top is (xmin, ymin) and right bottom is (xmax, ymax). Another common format is to use the center pixel to represent bounding box, for example (x, y, w, h) represents a bounding box with center at (x, y) and has width of w and height of h.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, they are the same thing as mentioned by @danyfang. These are very useful as we have the coordinates of a polygon and you can find out the center of the box, sides of the box, area of the box and all the operations performed in identifying the different characteristics of a polygon and hence an object.

left topmost point = xmin, ymin

right bottommost point = xmax, ymax

top rightmost point = xmax, ymin

left bottommost point = xmin, ymax

Hope this helps. Cheers.